# Controlling place holder text color from custom @IBDesignable UITextField class. Swift 4.2, Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, swift4.2

I have created Cocoa Touch Class:

- Sub Class Of `UITextField`
- And the file Name is `MyTextFieldStyle`

And here is the MyTextFieldStyle.swift file:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class MyTextFieldStyle: UITextField {

@IBInspectable var FavoriteTextColor : UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        self.textColor = FavoriteTextColor
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.textColor = self.FavoriteTextColor
}
```

}

How can I add these 3 controls,

- **placeHolder text color**
- **place holder font type**
- **place holder font size**

like 'FavoriteTextColor' above ? (Swift 4.2 & Xcode 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do my `IBDesignables` differently. I would put all my final assignment in the same function for an example here is my own custom `UITextField` I use.

```swift
@IBDesignable public class HooopTextfield: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBInspectable public var fontName: String? = "AvenirNext-Bold" {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var fontSize: CGFloat = 15 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var fontColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var customTextAlignment: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var letterSpacing: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var customPlaceholder: String? = nil {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var horizontalInset: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var verticalInset: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var selfDelegate: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if selfDelegate {
                self.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var baseLineOffset: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var placeholderColor: UIColor? = nil {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var requiredColor: UIColor? = nil {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var requiredCharacter: String = "*"{
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet public var nextField:HooopTextfield?

    /*** more inspectable var can be added **/

    override public func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: horizontalInset, dy: verticalInset)
    }

    override public func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: horizontalInset, dy: verticalInset)
    }

    func decorate() {
        // Setup border and corner radius
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        // Setup text style
        let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        switch customTextAlignment {
        case 2:
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .right
            break
        case 1:
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
            break
        default:
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
            break
        }
        var titleAttributes:[NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: fontColor,
            NSAttributedStringKey.kern: letterSpacing,
            NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset: baseLineOffset,
            NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ]
        if let _ = fontName {
            titleAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = UIFont(name: fontName!, size: fontSize)
        }
        if let _ = customPlaceholder {
            var placeholderAttributes = titleAttributes
            if let _ = placeholderColor {
                placeholderAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] = placeholderColor
            }
            let attributedPlaceholder = NSMutableAttributedString(string: customPlaceholder!, attributes: placeholderAttributes)
            if let _ = requiredColor {
                let range = (customPlaceholder! as NSString).range(of: requiredCharacter)
                attributedPlaceholder.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: requiredColor!, range: range)
            }
            self.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
        }
        self.defaultTextAttributes = titleAttributes
    }

    // MARK: - UITexfieldDelegate

    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if (nextField != nil) {
            nextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

I have basic stuff like `fontColor`, `fontSize`, `fontName`, same things for the placeholder. Then I have more visual things like `borderColor`, `cornerRadius`, `borderWidth`, etc. Finally I also have some inset rect positioning to align everything as I wish right from my storyboard.
I use `NSMutableAttributedString` for these because they are the most customisable, allowing me to also be able to color required fields and such.

Finally I also have a little `@IBOutlet` that also allows me to jump from one textfield to the next with the next button on the keyboard when combined with a boolean called `selfDelegate`.

Ask me any questions you want about this and play around with it you should be able to do anything you want with `@IBDesignable` I think.

EDIT 1:
Before I forget I recommend using a `decorate` or equivalent function because the order you apply your changes matter most of the time.

EDIT 2:
Fixed the errors, this was due most likely to swift changing how to use `NSAttributedString` attributes but strangely enough it seems the `placeholderAttributes` needed to be `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` but the `defaultTextAttributes` needed to be `[String: Any]` don't know why this would be the case. But it should work now.

EDIT 3:
Probably because I have a different version of Xcode or because it was a playground I had a message for defaultTextAttributes but I've refixed it by removing the `.rawValue` if it was the opposite that needed to be done, know that `NSAttributedStringKey.key.rawValue` will be a string and you can get the `NSAttributedStringKey` by using `NSAttributedStringKey.init(rawValue:String)`

Comment: Looks like great, let me examine it and then try to implement it. Thanks for now. @JamesWoodrow

Comment: Sure thing, feel free to take your time, I love `@IBDesignable` myself because I like the ability to do things from the storyboard and get an immediate preview of the result (except for certain things like the placeholder unfortunately you cannot preview a placeholder in the storyboard, but many things can be previewed and then used this way)

Comment: Understand. Yes, I agree, I also like the ability to do things from the storyboard and get an immediate preview of the result. Bur dear James, Does HooopTextfield.swift file works fine with Swift 4.2? I got some errors. @JamesWoodrow

Comment: I use swift 4.2 with Xcode 9.4.1 without any issues, what's the error ?

Comment: (1)Line: NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor,
(1)Error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.Key' to expected dictionary key type 'String'

(2)Line: titleAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: fontName!, size: fontSize)
(2)Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'NSAttributedString.Key'

Comment: (3) Line: placeholderAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = placeholderColor (3) Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'NSAttributedString.Key' (4) Line: let attributedPlaceholder = NSMutableAttributedString(string: customPlaceholder!, attributes: placeholderAttributes) (4) Error: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?'

Comment: (5)Line: self.defaultTextAttributes = titleAttributes (5) Error: Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type '[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]' (Total 5 Lines, 5 Errors)

Comment: Hm, seems like I didn't notice any errors because I was using mine as part or a private UI pod, I'll edit it in a playground to update my answer fixing this

Comment: Thanks. But if it big issue I mean if it takes your time please don't do it. I try to solve it.

Comment: Fixed the errors I don't seem to get any more errors from my Playground but if you still have some, I'll look into it because that might become a future error for myself.

Comment: I have fixed 5-6 has been renamed error. Right now We have only one. Line: self.defaultTextAttributes = titleAttributes Error: Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type '[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]'  @JamesWoodrow

Comment: fixed by removing `.rawValue` and then that meant I could remove my loop made to convert rawValue keys to their `NSAttributedStringKey` equivalents

Comment: Dear James thanks a lot. The last edit needs 3-5 'has been reNamed errors' I did them(clicked Fix button) It works fine. Thanks really appreciated. If you want me to share Please tell me how and where can I post it? @JamesWoodrow

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Awesome work. can we open font suggestion like you did for color suggestion in storyboard ? Thanks